# "No module named argv"

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a very simple Python app, but I've been immediately stopped by the fact that Python can't find argv!

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Apr  9 2014, 11:48:52) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys.argv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named argv
>>>
```

What would cause this problem?

I thought perhaps the upgrade from Lion to Mavericks broke my Python install completely, but I've tried installing via homebrew, and I'm pretty sure I've set it up such that I get the Homebrew installation at `/usr/local/bin/python` instead of the default OS X install. This didn't help.

Comment: from sys import argv

Comment: It's because sys.argv is not a module, `sys` is a module

Comment: Had you googled this you would have realised that no one uses the above syntax (for reasons specified below) :p

Comment: The interesting question is not "why doesn't this work", but "Why did you think it would?" (I'm not trying to be snarking; it can be illuminating to work through the thought process that led you to trying invalid code.)

Comment: I guess because the Python documentation wasn't clear enough about the nuances of importing early enough in the tutorial process.

Comment: @chepner does that mean the import keyword can only be used to import a module and not a module's members?

Comment: @RaynerDaCruz That depends on precisely what you mean. The `import` statement does two things: it locates and executes a file to create a module, if necessary, and it adds some names to the current namespace.

Comment: @chepner So for example the OP is trying to import the sys module's member argv. But obviously it doesn't work and I don't understand why it doesn't work. So I have come to the assumption that the import keyword cannot be used to import a module's member but it can only import a module. I don't know if my assumption is correct or not.

Comment: You can't use `import sys.argv`, but you can use `from sys import argv`. The thing you import must be a module, but the `from ... import ...` form lets you only add some names defined by a module into the current namespace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only import the `sys` module. `sys.argv` is a variable inside this module, you cannot import variables. Try:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.argv
[whatever]
```

Alternatively, you can use `from sys import argv` and just use `argv`.

Answer (score 5):

```
from sys import argv
```

or

```
import sys
sys.argv
```

Comment: Why does the above work but not how the OP is trying to import? Can you please explain, or point me to a resource which explains why.

Answer (score 0):

The module is sys:

```
import sys
```

which has a member called argv:

```
sys.argv
```

Answer (score 0):

`argv` is a list object stuck on the sys module.  You can only `import` modules.

Just `import sys` and use `sys.argv`